# Solr fails to start after java update on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, solr

After running apt-get update && apt-get upgrade on an ubuntu 12.04 box and rebooting, the Solr service that had previously been running without issue under tomcat6 fails to start, with the following error:

```
530  [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
564  [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – null:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/CryptoPrimitive
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.<clinit>(ProtocolVersion.java:113)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$ConservativeSSLContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:464)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1277)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:142)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:85)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setMaxConnections(HttpClientUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:33)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.configureClient(HttpClientUtil.java:133)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:109)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory.init(HttpShardHandlerFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I tried switching to Tomcat7/OpenJDK7, but received exactly the same error. Tomcat itself runs fine, but solr doesn't start and returns a 503 when you try to access the /solr path.

So this was an instance of Solr that was working perfectly prior to the apt-get upgrade, and now isn't... I'm not sure what to do aside from trying the Oracle JDK instead, but I've never had to do that before on Ubuntu and I'm not sure why it should be necessary in this case.

java -version reports:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Thanks for any thoughts you may have!

Comment: that's all what you get on the log?
Can you print the result of apt-get update / upgrade if you still have it?

Comment: I added further error results, and also added my current java information... Unfortunately I don't have the results of the apt-get anymore, sorry!

Comment: In my opinion after you update/upgrade something in the classpath was broken.
generally java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError means that the JVM is not able to find or load a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time
Can you verify if all the installation directories are present (Solr, data, java)

Comment: `CryptoPrimitive` came with 1.7 - it cannot work with 1.6, but it should with OpenJDK7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... Turned out that I just needed to totally remove and reinstall tomcat6, and all associated packages, via:

```
apt-get remove tomcat6
apt-get autoremove
```

I also had OpenJDK7 installed due to that attempt to fix the issue, so I also ran:

```
apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

After that I just did:

```
apt-get install tomcat6
```

And it worked as expected. All of the prior solr setup was already present, so everything came back immediately, no indexing required. As Marvin said above, `CryptoPrimitive` should have only come with 1.7, so I have no idea why it had this issue after the upgrade, since we had been running 1.6 the whole time.

Anyway, hopefully this helps someone else in the future, thanks for the comments, all!